# How to make absolute positioned, table dialog's cell widths not be squished by relative positioned, floated container?

Tags: html, css

I am making a date picker dialog where there is a left arrow button, a chart of month dates, and a right arrow button.

The dialog is being horizontally squished by its container, when the container is floated. I'd like to be able to float the container, so I can put another container next to it.

[image]

How can I make it so that the dialog does not get squished?

In the code below, you can see the squishing go away by commenting out the float rule.

```css
.selector-container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.selector {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

td.side {
  width: 40px;
}

table.center td {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="selector-container">
        <div class="selector">
          <p>Select some stuff</p>
        </div>
        <table class="dialog">
          <tr>
            <td class="side">
              <
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                Oct 2017
              </div>
              <table class="center">
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td>8</td>
                  <td>9</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>13</td>
                  <td>14</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td class="side">
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="selector-container">
        <div class="selector">
          <p>Select some stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I lost you at `left and right arrows` ... please explain how it should look? Do you have some design of what you're after? and image at least or a sketch?

Comment: I updated my description. Also, updated the code, too. Running the code snippet visually shows the date picker.

Comment: I'm still absolutely not positive what's the expected result. Also why do you use the second `.selector` AFTER the calendar - if it's actual place should be at the top?. Please, please use Paint, use Photoshop, use whatever, just make CLEAR and without doubts what are your intents. From the code, when I remove the float:left rule I'm even more confused.

Comment: Ok, I'll photoshop and update question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function buildCalendar( mm_dd_yyyy ) {
  
  var MN = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
      WD = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
      date = !mm_dd_yyyy? new Date() : new Date(mm_dd_yyyy),
      y = date.getFullYear(),
      m = date.getMonth(),
      pfx = (date.getDay() + 7) % 7,     // How many prefix empty cells we miss?
      mtot = new Date(y, m+1, 0).getDate(),
      sfx = 7 - (pfx + mtot + 7) % 7, // How many suffix empty cells we miss?
      html = "<table>";
  
  // MONTH YEAR
  html += "<tr><th colspan='7'>"+ MN[m] +" "+ y +"</th></tr>";
  // WEEK DAYS
  html += "<tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < WD.length; i++) html += "<th>" + WD[i] + "</th>";
  html += "</tr>";
  // CALENDAR
  html += "<tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < pfx; i++) html += "<td></td>"; // Empty Prefix
  for (var i = 0; i < mtot; i++) {
    html += "<td>" + (i+1) + "</td>";
    if (!((i+pfx+1)%7)) html += "</tr><tr>"; // Add a new week row?
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < sfx; i++) html += "<td></td>"; // Empty Suffix
  return html + "</tr></table>";
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[data-calendar]"), function (el) {
  el.innerHTML = buildCalendar(el.dataset.calendar);
});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/
*{margin: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}html,body {height: 100%;font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;}
/* Flexy */
.flex-row  {display:flex; flex-direction:row;}
.flex-col  {display:flex; flex-direction:column;}
.flex-grow {flex:1;}
.flex-child-hcenter{justify-content: center;}
.flex-self-vcenter{align-self: center;}



/* Calendar */
.calendar {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #0bf;
}
.calendar .arr{
  padding: 8px;
}
[data-calendar] td,
[data-calendar] tr{
  text-align: center;
  padding:4px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-grow">FOO</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">BAR</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-self-vcenter arr">&lsaquo;</div>
    <div data-calendar="07/01/2017"><!-- I'm lazy. Fill this using JS --></div>
    <div class="flex-self-vcenter arr">&rsaquo;</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="calendar">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-grow">FOO</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">BAR</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-self-vcenter arr">&lsaquo;</div>
    <div data-calendar="08/01/2017"><!-- I'm lazy. Fill this using JS --></div>
    <div class="flex-self-vcenter arr">&rsaquo;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Roko!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, which is to give the dialog a width, and use percentages to give sub-part widths.

```css
.selector-container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.selector {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

td.side {
  width: 10%;
}

table.center {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="selector-container">
        <div class="selector">
          <p>Select some stuff</p>
        </div>
        <table class="dialog">
          <tr>
            <td class="side">
              <
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                June 2017
              </div>
              <table class="center">
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>7</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td>8</td>
                  <td>9</td>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>13</td>
                  <td>14</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td class="side">
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="selector-container">
        <div class="selector">
          <p>Select some stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```